# Wordpress Plugin doesn't have the excepted behaviour

Tags: wordpress, plugins

The following code is supposed to generate a plugin called "Zero Plugin Random" that creates a table in the database. The plugin is detected and appears in the administration panel, but the table is actually not created as excepted. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Zero PLugin Test
Plugin URI: http://zero-plugin.com
Description: Random Plugin
Version: 0.1
Author: Midnight Falcon
Author URI: http://website.com
License: GPL2
*/

class Zero{

  public static function init_table_members(){

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}members;");

  }
  public function __construct(){
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, [$this, 'init_table_members']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I believe the code is missing the table structure, the indexes, and the class is not instantiated as well.

Here is a quick POC of how you can create a custom table in WordPress

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Zero PLugin Test
Plugin URI: http://zero-plugin.com
Description: Random Plugin
Version: 0.1
Author: Midnight Falcon
Author URI: http://website.com
License: GPL2
*/

if ( ! defined('WPINC') ) die; // no direct access

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_create_db' );
function my_plugin_create_db() {

    global $wpdb;

  $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'members';

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
        views smallint(5) NOT NULL,
        clicks smallint(5) NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );

}
```

And here are a couple of very complete and explanatory guides:

https://deliciousbrains.com/creating-custom-table-php-wordpress/
https://pippinsplugins.com/create-database-tables-when-plugin-is-activated/

Hope it helps ;)